# What things to be aware of when using the with-statement for own classes?

Tags: python, with-statement

I am planning to implement C++-like constructor/destructor functionality to one of my Python classes using the handy [with](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) statement. I've come accross this statement only for file IO up to now, but I thought it would be rather helpful for connection-based communication tasks as well, say [sockets](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) or [database connections](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors). Things that eventually need to be closed.

In PEP 343 (linked above) it is said, that `with` needs the methods `__enter__` and `__exit__`, and my straight-forward implementation of this appears to work as intended.

```
class MyConnection:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def __enter__(self):
    print "constructor"
    # TODO: open connections and stuff
    # make the connection available in the with-block
    return self 
  def __exit__(self, *args):
    print "destructor"
    # TODO: close connections and stuff

with MyConnection() as c:
  # TODO: do something with c
  pass
```

Which yields the output (as expected):

```
constructor
destructor
```

Should it really be this easy? What are the things to consider besides this? Why do so many libraries (apparantly) lack this functionality yet? Have I missed something?

Comment: How will you pass arguments in __exit__() then ?

Comment: `__exit__` takes three arguments: exception type, its value and traceback (3 `None`s if no exception occurred). Python passes them as positional args so `**kwargs` isn't needed.

Comment: Read the PEP, it explain all the finer points.

Comment: @yak : that's True, fixed it.

Comment: @Arseny : I will avoid any need to pass arguments to __exit__() myself.

Comment: @JochenRitzel : I was aiming on practical experience, what pitfalls there are when using this approach. Maybe a reason why it's not a common feature for all sorts of tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(a) It's that easy

(b) An alternative approach is a decorator function, which decorates functions (and classes, but not for this use-case), and also allows code to be called both before and after the wrapped function. Those seem slightly more common.

(c) I don't think you're missing anything.

Comment: Context manager also allows code before (`__enter__`) and after (`__exit__`).

Comment: @yak: What part of my answer leads you to believe that I am unaware of that?

Answer (score 0):

One issue I have run into while attempting to implement 'with' functionality in my libraries is figuring out an elegant way to handle failure exceptions.  Given the following:

```
class open_file_for_read(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = "./does_not_exist.txt"
        self.fileobj = None

    def __enter__(self):
        print("Opening file %s for read" % self.filename)
        self.fileobj = open(name=self.filename, mode='r')
        return self.fileobj

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.fileobj.close()


with open_file_for_read() as fh:
    for li in fh.readlines():
        print(li)
```

What is the recommended method for handling the inevitable "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './does_not_exist.txt'" exception?  There's always the 'try/except' approach

```
try:
    with open_file_for_read() as fh:
except IOError:
    ...
except XXX:
    ...
...
```

This direct approach works, but I think it detracts from the simplicity of using the 'with' construct.  Perhaps someone out there has a more elegant solution?

Appologies for this being more of a question than an answer, but it is one of the issues I've run into when attempting to implement 'with'.